# JavaScript - Keep trailing zeroes

Tags: javascript, parsing, trailing

I want to parse a string and I used `parseFloat()`, but it removes all the trailing zeroes. How to prevent this - I need to parse the string exactly - if I have 2.5000, I need exactly the same result as a floating-point number - 2.5000.

Comment: `2.50000` and `2.5` are *the exact same* number. If you want to keep trailing zeroes, you'll have to use a string.

Comment: you will have to reformat it to display it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do

```
parseFloat(2.5).toFixed(4);
```

If you need exactly the same floating point you may have to figure out the amount

```
function parseFloatToFixed(string) {
  return parseFloat(string).toFixed(string.split('.')[1].length);
}

console.log(parseFloatToFixed('2.54355'));
```

But i don't really understand why you even need to use parseFloat then? Numbers in javascript do not retain the floating-point count. so you would have to keep them as strings, and calculate against them as floats.

Also don't forget toFixed may have weird rounding issues in different browsers, for example

```
console.log((0.1).toFixed(20));
```

Comment: Thank you - that was the result I needed.

Comment: @Isadora see you have string(a) you convert into float using parseFloat and chad_scira is converting float into string (c). so c=a here so you really don't need this conversion.