# .toFixed() returns a string? how can I convert that to floating number

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I tried with the example value x = 123,i want two precision. So, i use x.toFixed(2). Then i will get the output "123.00"
but i want the output as 123.00 which is floating number with decimals.

```
var x = 123
x.toFixed(2);
output: "123.00"
expected: 123.00
```

[image]

Comment: If you convert it to a float, it won't keep the trailing 0s

Comment: No after converting to float also it will give you number only 123 not floating point

Comment: @SandeepBhaskar Give a proof? But even after converting into float, 123 is an integer and not a decimal number right? `123` and `123.00` and `123.00000` are all the same.

Comment: @SandeepBhaskar So if you want the trailing 0, you need to use a string

Comment: That's exactly my answer says... `:)`

Comment: There is a big difference producing a number to _show_ and one to use for _counting_. The one to use for count is not gonna keep trailing zero's as that is not how number works, then one for show can.

Answer (score 3):

A floating point notation or decimal number is not something explicitly declared. When the decimal point has nothing after the point, i.e., `.0` It becomes an integer.

The `.toFixed()` is just for aesthetic purposes only. It also helps you to rounds off to the number of decimals too.

> *`2.50000` and `2.5` are the exact same number. If you want to keep trailing zeroes, you'll have to use a string.*

When I try to do this on my Chrome Console:

[image]

You can see that even when you do a strict type-checking, the decimals are considered like comments by the JavaScript parser. It might be a bit unclear to understand for developers coming from statically typed or strongly typed languages like Java & C#, where you can have separate float and double types.

Related: [JavaScript - Keep trailing zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24889498).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183857/discussion-between-sandeep-bhaskar-and-praveen-kumar-purushothaman).